# Нужна помощь с задачей Python

Tags: python

Напишите функцию `convert_to_python_case(text)`, которая принимает в качестве аргумента строку в «верблюжьем регистре» и преобразует его в «змеиный регистр».

```
print(convert_to_python_case('ThisIsCamelCased'))
print(convert_to_python_case('IsPrimeNumber'))
```

должен выводить:

```
this_is_camel_cased
is_prime_number
```

код не проходит один тест

```
def convert_to_pythom_case(text):    
a = text[0].lower()    
for _ in text:    
    if _ == _.lower():      
        a += _      
    elif _ == _.upper() and _ != text[0]:    
        a += "_" + _.lower()    
return a    

s = input()  
print(convert_to_pythom_case(s))
```

при вводе `MyMethodThatDoSomething`
выдает `myethod_that_do_something`

Comment: Решение через регулярное выражение рассматривается?

Answer (score 1):

Решение с использованием регулярных выражений

```
import re

def convert_to_pythom_case(text):
    return re.sub('([A-Z][a-z]*)', r'\1_', text).lower().rstrip('_')

for w in 'MyMethodThatDoSomething', 'ThisIsCamelCased', 'AAAA', 'AAbbCCdd':
    print(convert_to_pythom_case(w))
```

```
my_method_that_do_something
this_is_camel_cased
a_a_a_a
a_abb_c_cdd
```

Answer (score 0):

у вас ошибка в этой строке:

```
elif _ == _.upper() and _ != text[0]:
```

если первая буква равна другой большой букве, то большая буква будет пропущена, как у вас и случилось

например "MMMMMMM" ваш алгоритм превратит в "m"

Я бы сделал алгоритм по другому:

1. разбить строку на слова, где слово начинается с большой буквы
2. все слова перевести в нижний регистр
3. соединить слова через "_"

```
def convert_to_pythom_case(text):
    words = []
    tmp = ""

    for l in text:
        if l.isupper():
            if tmp:
                words.append(tmp)
            tmp = ""
        tmp += l
    if tmp:
        words.append(tmp)

    res = '_'.join(map(str.lower, words))

    return res

print(convert_to_pythom_case("MyMethodThatDoSomething"))
```

Comment: спасибо большое!